# Capturar imagem por url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, imagem

Tenho a seguinte url:

http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.3.1/img/champion/{{nome}}.png

Substituindo a palavra `nome` por um nome específico e navegando até a página em questão o site mostra uma imagem.png. Como posso capturar essa imagem usando o angularjs?

Ex: http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.3.1/img/champion/Nautilus.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando `ng-src`. Exemplo a seguir:

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

app.controller('SampleController', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.codigos = ['Nautilus','Azir','Ekko'];
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-resource.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">

  <div ng-controller="SampleController">
    
    <img ng-src='http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.3.1/img/champion/{{i}}.png' ng-repeat='i in codigos'/>

  </div>
</div>
```